# Performing Magento CRUD operations when user clicks radio button

Tags: magento-enterprise, php, module, controllers, phtml

**Hello Everyone**

I am new to Magento and have been having trouble performing basic CRUD
operations , specifically Update..

**The Scenario**

There are two radio buttons (ON, OFF) when a user clicks the off button
it he should be moved to the General customer group in the db
Likewise when the  user clicks ON he should be moved to the Auto customer group in the db

***NOTE:***  these operations need to happen on the user click

**The Code**
*view.phtml located /magento/app/design/frontend/default/MAGXXXXX/template/autorefill*

```
<form action="???" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="auto-refill" value="On" onClick = "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('test/index/save') ?>" />On<br>
    <input type="radio" name="auto-refill" value="Off" onClick = "???" />Off
</form>
```

---

*AutoFillUpdate.php located /magento/app/code/local/AppName/AutoFillUpdate/Model*

```
<?php

class AppName_AutoFillUpdate  {
} ?>
```

---

*IndexController.php located in /magento/app/code/local/Custom123Recycle/AutoFillUpdate/controllers*

```
<?php
class Custom123Recycle_AutoFillUpdate extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

  public function indexAction()
   {
      //TODO
   }

  public function saveAction()
  {
    //Might be where update customer group should happen

   $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
   $groupId = $customer->getGroupId();
   $group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId);
   $groupCode = $group->getCode();

 if (groupCode == 'General')
    $customer.setGroupId(2).save();
 else 
  $customer.setGroupId(1).save();

  }

}
?>
```

**What I Know**

I was told in order to manipulate the db I would need
to create a new module which I have done its called AutoFillUpdate
which resides in /magento/app/code/local/AppName/AutoFillUpdate

Inside this folder is are the basic Magento folders (Block, Helper, Model, controllers, etc, sql)

**Points of Confusion**

I am interested in updating the customer DB..so I would think I would be okay getting the module using Mage:getModel('customer/session') and then just updating that specific customer if they click the button, Why would I need to create a new module if the customer that has the db resides in core ? OR am I mistaken..

I am confused on how to my created module links with the view.phtml template

**Questions**
What value/string should go in the form action & onClick elements in view.phtml

Should the update functionality happen inside the controller indexController.php?

Would implementing listeners be more suitable ?

**Any guidance of any complexity is welcomed, Thanks in advance**

Comment: could you please add information, how much you know about javascript, javascript events and doing ajax requests?

Comment: @Flyingmana I know I good amount of javascript, havent heard of javascript events and have done limited work with ajax requests